# Is there a way to use 'new XXXX' depending of parameters?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project which emulates a scientific calculator using the reversed polish notation. My litterals, such as "1", "1.23","2/3", etc. are stored in a stack with their types. For instance "1" will be stored as an Integer, "1.23" as a Double, etc, using my types (I defined Double, Integer, etc for various reasons).

```
class Litteral {
  public:
     virtual QString toString () const = 0;
};
```

I want to do as follows : when the user enters an operator, such as +, I need to pop() twice on my stack, execute the operation, and push(). I already have done the recognization of the operators. When the user types +, I execute a given algorithm. 
My problem is that when the + is recognized and the two pop() are done, I need  to really execute + and I need to create an object of the correct type.
For instance if I had an Integer and a Double, I'd have to :

```
Litteral* l = new Double(pop1+pop2);
```

But if I had two Integers, I'd have to :

```
Litteral* l = new Integer(pop1 + pop2);
```

Etc... 
I could use a large amount of 'if' to execute the correct "new XXXX()", but I feel like this isn't a good solution.
I also thought about using a template method, using  to execute the corresponding algorithm, but I'd have to create as many versions of this function as there are possible combinations. It is still humanly possible, but again, it doesn't feel clean. 
Is there any clean way to do that ?

Thanks

Edit :
For instance, when I pop 2 Integers, I want to execute a given operation. The result of this operation must be an Integer. But the result is not always an Integer, it depends of the things I pop'd. If it was an Integer and a Double, the result would have been a Double. So the type of the 'new' I have to do depends of the things I pop'd.
And I don't want to implement that with a switch/ multiples 'if'. I don't want to do that :

```
if ((typeid(*q1) == typeid(Integer)) && (typeid(*q2) == typeid(Double)))  { //...}
```

Edit 2:

```
Literal& pop1 = stack.top(); 
stack.pop(); 
Literal& pop2 = stack.top(); 
stack.pop(); 
Literal& toAdd = (*pop1.clone() + *pop2.clone());
```

Error : no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Literal' and 'Literal')

Classes :

```
class Literal { 
    public: virtual QString toString () const = 0; 
      virtual int getValue() const = 0; 
      virtual Litteral * clone() const = 0; 
      virtual Litteral& operator+(const Integer& l) = 0; 
}; 

class Integer: public Literal { 
    friend class LitteralManager; 
    int value; 
    public: 
      Integer(int v) :value(v) {} 
      Integer(const Entier& e) { value = e.getValue(); }; 
      virtual QString toString () const; 
      int getValue() const { return value; } 
      virtual Entier& operator+(const Entier& e);
      Entier * clone() const; 
};
```

Comment: `pop1` and `pop2` in your example are instances of either `Double` or `Integer`, right? If so, how is their `operator+` defined? Can't you just make it return the appropriate type and not have to `new` when using it at all?

Comment: *.. as Integer, "1.23" as a Double, etc*. Please do expand on *etc*. How many types in total do you expect to have?

Comment: I'll have 7 types of Litterals.

Comment: I was trying to define operator+, but the thing is that when I pop from my stack, everything I get is a Litteral, I lose the true type. So if I try to do :
pop1+pop2, it's trying to find `operator+(const Litteral& l1,constLitteral&l2)`, which doesn't exist. If it did, I could have use `new XXX`given the operator+ I'd be in.

Comment: @Chuck But if that doesn't exist, how can your code work at all? I mean even if you get around the "which class do I `new` issue", `new WhatEver(pop1 + pop2)` can't compile if there's no `operator+` defined for `pop1` and `pop2`.

Comment: @sepp2k I'm not trying to `new XXX(pop1 + pop2)`, I want the operator+ itself to do the `new XXX()`.
For instance when I am in `operator+(const Integer& int1, const Integer& int2)`, I can : `return new Integer(int1.getValue()+int2.getValue())`, where `getValue()` gives me the int stored in Integer.
As stated above, the thing is that it doesn't find the proper operator+, because pop1 and pop2 are Litterals. So it tries to find `operator+(const Litteral& l1, const Litteral& l2)`.

Comment: @Chuck I was referring to the code in your question where you're doing `new Double(pop1+pop2);` and `new Integer(pop1+pop2);`. You said that the problem is that you don't know which one to pick. And I said that neither of those even work if you don't have an `operator+` (and they're not necessary if you do have an operator+ that already returns the proper type).

Comment: @sepp2k I forgot to use the getValue() function.
It would be `new Integer(pop1.getValue()+pop2.getValue());`. But I wouldn't use that if I can make the operator+ solution to work.

Comment: And regarding your issue with finding the operator: That should be solvable with virtual inheritance. You'll still need some kind of conditional in the operator definitions to handle the case where you're getting operands of different types though (I'd imagine something like a numeric conversion precedence would help there).

Comment: @sepp2k _That should be solvable with virtual inheritance._ Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @Chuck Define a purely virtual operator+ in the base class and then implement it in the subclasses.

Comment: @sepp2k It actually doesn't work.
In Litteral : `virtual Litteral& operator+(const Litteral& l) = 0;`
Now in Integer I want to define what to do when I add 2 Integers :
`Integer& operator+(const Integer& e) {
        return *(new Integer(getValue()+e.getValue()));
    }`
And that doesn't work because it is expecting a Litteral, so it isn't the same function.
Now I could do the following in Litteral : `virtual Litteral& operator+(const Integer& l) = 0;`, but Integer is defined after the class Litteral.

Comment: @Chuck Yes, the argument type still needs to be literal. As I said, you still need to handle the case that two different types are being added.

Comment: @sepp2k Any suggestion on how to do that ? I've to admit I'm a bit struggling with this thing :'( Doing this with a switch is messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

struct Double;
struct Integer;

struct Literal {
    virtual Literal* operator + (const Literal&) const = 0;
    virtual Literal* operator + (const Double&)  const = 0;
    virtual Literal* operator + (const Integer&) const = 0;};

struct Double : Literal {
    Literal* operator + (const Literal& rhs) const {
        return rhs + *this;}

    Literal* operator + (const Double& rhs) const {
        return new Double;}

    Literal* operator + (const Integer& rhs) const {
        return new Double;}};

struct Integer : Literal {
    Literal* operator + (const Literal& rhs) const {
        return rhs + *this;}

    Literal* operator + (const Double& rhs) const {
        return new Double;}

    Literal* operator + (const Integer& rhs) const {
        return new Integer;}};

int main () {
    {
    Literal* p = new Double;
    Literal* q = new Double;
    Literal* r = *p + *q;
    assert(typeid(*r) == typeid(Double));
    }

    {
    Literal* p = new Double;
    Literal* q = new Integer;
    Literal* r = *p + *q;
    assert(typeid(*r) == typeid(Double));
    }

    {
    Literal* p = new Integer;
    Literal* q = new Double;
    Literal* r = *p + *q;
    assert(typeid(*r) == typeid(Double));
    }

    {
    Literal* p = new Integer;
    Literal* q = new Integer;
    Literal* r = *p + *q;
    assert(typeid(*r) == typeid(Integer));
    }

    return 0;}
```

Comment: Missed the whole thing about this solution. My bad. It works perfectly. Thanks !

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm so glad it fit what you needed. That pattern is called double dispatch. Still far from ideal. Doesn't scale well. Is it too crass to ask for you to upvote the answer? :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

struct Literal {
    virtual Literal* clone () const = 0;};

struct Double : Literal {
    Double* clone () const {
        return new Double(*this);}};

struct Integer : Literal {
    Integer* clone () const {
        return new Integer(*this);}};

int main () {
    stack<Literal*> x;

    x.push(new Double());
    x.push(new Integer());

    Literal* p = x.top();    // the Integer
    x.pop();
    Literal* q = p->clone(); // create a new Integer

    assert(typeid(*q) == typeid(Integer));

    return 0;}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But I don't see how the factory is helping me here. I probably didn't explain my problem properly. I've edited my post to make it more clear.

Comment: There's no obvious way to know that Double should be preferred over Integer. I was mis-assuming that the type of the first poped object should dictate the result, but I now see what you're trying to do. Take a look at how iterator traits work. They form a hierarchy that lets algorithms choose the most appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

class Literal {
public:
  virtual ~Literal() = default;
};

class Double : public Literal {
public:
  Double(double val) : m_val(val) { }
  Double(const Double&) = default;
  Double(Double&&) = default;
  ~Double() = default;

  double value() const { return m_val; }

private:
  double m_val;
};

class Integer : public Literal {
public:
  Integer(int val) : m_val(val) { }
  Integer(const Integer&) = default;
  Integer(Integer&&) = default;
  ~Integer() = default;

  int value() const { return m_val; }

private:
  int m_val;
};

template <typename T> struct make_literal_result;
template <> struct make_literal_result<int> {
  using type = Integer;
};
template<> struct make_literal_result<double> {
  using type = Double;
};
template <typename T>
using make_literal_result_t = typename make_literal_result<T>::type;

template <typename T> std::unique_ptr<make_literal_result_t<T>> make_literal(T x) {
  return std::make_unique<make_literal_result_t<T>>(x);
}

template <typename Res, typename Fn>
Res dynamic_apply(Fn f, const Literal* val) {
  auto vald = dynamic_cast<const Double*>(val);
  if (vald != nullptr)
    return f(vald->value());
  auto vali = dynamic_cast<const Integer*>(val);
  if (vali != nullptr)
    return f(vali->value());
  throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid type");
}

std::unique_ptr<Literal> dynamic_plus(const Literal* x, const Literal* y) {
  auto curried_plus = [](auto val1) -> std::function<std::unique_ptr<Literal>(const Literal*)> {
    return [val1](const Literal* y) -> std::unique_ptr<Literal> {
      return dynamic_apply<std::unique_ptr<Literal>>([val1](auto val2) {
        return make_literal(val1 + val2);
      }, y);
    };
  };
  auto plus_x = dynamic_apply<std::function<std::unique_ptr<Literal>(const Literal*)>>(curried_plus, x);
  return plus_x(y);
}

int main() {
  Double x { 2.5 };
  Integer y { 3 };
  auto sum = dynamic_plus(&x, &y);
  auto sum_Double = dynamic_cast<Double*>(sum.get());
  assert(sum_Double != nullptr);
  std::cout << "sum is: " << sum_Double->value() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The general idea of `dynamic_plus` is: the result stored in `plus_x` is a function taking `const Literal*` and returning `std::unique_ptr<Literal>`, whose body uses `dynamic_apply` on a generic lambda to do its work.  To construct `plus_x`, in turn, is another application of `make_literal` to a higher-level function.  (Then, we also need to do some type erasure using `std::function` in order to have some common type for that `dynamic_apply` to return.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I started to look into another solution, but if it does not work, I'll come back to your post. Thanks again for taking time to answer!